# Test if a word is composed of alpha characters, white spaces and periods?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex that would test if a word is composed of letters (alpha characters), white spaces, and periods (.). I need this to use for validating names that is entered in my database.

This is what I currently use:

```
preg_match('/^[\pL\s]+$/u',$foo)
```

It works fine for checking alpha characters and whitespaces, but rejects names with periods as well. I hope you guys can help as I have no idea how to use regex.

Comment: `^[\pL\s.]+$` use this

Comment: Note that these expressions also "validate" names that consist entirely of dots or spaces like `. . ... ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a dot to the character class so that it would match a literal dot also.

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L}.\s]+$/u',$foo)
```

OR

```
preg_match('/^[\pL.\s]+$/u',$foo)
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[\pL.\s]+` Matches any character in the list one or more times. `\pL` matches any Kind of letter from any language.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit; I was reading the regex and thinking "why on earth is he looking for an escaped `p` letter?"

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should satisfy your condition:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s.]+$/',$foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this link, you will find all the information you need to figure regex out with PHP. [PHP Regex Cheat Sheet](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php#basics)

Basically, if you want to add the period you add . :

```
preg_match('/^[\pL\s\.]+$/u',$foo)
```

Enjoy! :)